Including standalone tikz in beamer
I have a stand.tex that contains the following latex code:
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw horizontal line
    \draw[->] (0.5,0) -- (19,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I can simply include this with \input{stand.tex} in a regular document. When I'm trying to include this in a presentation, it goes awry. I tried:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,external}



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\input{standalone.tex}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Whilst this is showing me the tikz compiled figure, it also prints [tikz,border=10pt]standalone into the slide, together with the complaint that the beginning of stand.tex can only be used in preamble. How do I include this correctly in my presentation? Preferably, I'd not touch stand.tex, since it's already being used elsewhere.

There is a file standalone.tex in the standalone package. So don't name your own file standalone.tex. And also note, that you cannot “simply include” a file with \documentclass or other preamble code “with \input” into another document, because only one \documentclass per document is allowed and \documentclass inside the body (between \begin{document} and \end{document}) is also not allowed. This is independent from using beamer or using TikZ.

Why not include the PDF generated using the standalone file?

@cabohah I don't want to compile the other document separately (I'm using overleaf)

Regarding `standalone.tex', I was using that for illustrative purposes here, not the actual name -- but I changed to reduce confusion

You could use the standalone package:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\input{stand.tex}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


(note that a 19cm wide line will be too big for a beamer frame as well as a "normal" document)

Works like a charm! Good catch with the too big line. Would there be any way to scale down the included document, or is that not possible in this setup?

@FooBar You could scale it down to fit the width of the text area, but if you have more graphics in your presentation, this can lead to inconsistent widths of the lines. Usually designing images with the target width in mind will give better results.

You never “can simply include” a file with \documentclass or other preamble code “with \input” into another document, because only one \documentclass per document is allowed and \documentclass inside the body (between \begin{document} and \end{document}) is also not allowed. This is independent from using beamer or using TikZ or standalone. For example:
\begin{filecontents}{stand.tex}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw horizontal line
    \draw[->] (0.5,0) -- (19,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{stand.tex}
\end{document}

also fails with:

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 \documentclass
                  [tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

So you are wrong, when you say:

I can simply include this with \input{stand.tex} in a regular document

One possible answer to solve this, could be the usage of package subfile → 'Can only be used in preamble' Error when using \input for a chapter.
Another suggestion could be to use shell-escape to first generate a PDF from stand.tex and then include the generated PDF:
\begin{filecontents}{stand.tex}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw horizontal line
    \draw[->] (0.5,0) -- (19,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\ShellEscape{pdflatex stand.tex}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{stand}
\end{document}

Note: This needs activation of shell-escape, e.g., run with pdflatex --shell-escape foo.tex instead of pdflatex foo.tex.
One advantage of this solution is, that you can also use additional option for \includegraphics:
\begin{filecontents}{stand.tex}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw horizontal line
    \draw[->] (0.5,0) -- (19,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\ShellEscape{pdflatex stand.tex}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{stand}
\end{document}

But in your case when using a file, where the document preamble is limited to the usage of one \documentclass command, you can indeed do it more simple:
\begin{filecontents}{stand.tex}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw horizontal line
    \draw[->] (0.5,0) -- (19,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% note: also loads pgf
\newcommand\inputsimpledocument[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \RenewDocumentCommand\documentclass{omo}{}
    \renewenvironment{document}{}{}%
    \input{#1}
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\inputsimpledocument{stand.tex}
\end{document}

Note: The usage of filecontents was only to have a single test file (generating the sub-file on it's own). However, usage of filecontents is not part of the suggestion. You can indeed also use physically separated files and remove the filecontents environment from all the examples.
